# jquery active class to menu item based on current url

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that should add an active css class to the menu item if menu item url == current url:

```
$("#accordion a").each(function() 
{   
    if (this.href.search(window.location.hostname) != -1)
    {
        $(this).addClass("active-sidebar-link");
    }
});
```

but this adds the class to all the menu items. any tips?

Comment: `window.location.hostname` would return you the page hostname i.e. `stackoverflow.com`. You should instead use `location.href` or `location.pathname` to get the correct match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#accordion a").each(function() {   
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active-sidebar-link");
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, however it will break if the URL has a fragment.  For example `domain.com/folder/#top`.

Comment: Using `pathname` instead of `href` should help.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#accordion a[href="'+ window.location.hostname +'"]').addClass('active-sidebar-link');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with jQuery, you can:

```
$("#accordion a").addClass(function(){
  return this.href === window.location 
    ? "active-sidebar-link" 
    : "" ;
});
```

However, there's a far better way to style current-page links. This generally involves given the `body` element a classname that corresponds to your links:

```
<body class="home">
   <a class="home" href="foo.html">Home</a>
   <a class="contact" href="bar.html">Contact</a>
</body>
```

In this case, you would select the active link styles like this:

```
body.home a.home,
body.contact a.contact {
  color: green;
}
```

This method doesn't require JavaScript to set the initial styles, which is always good.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter function:

```
$("#accordion a")
.filter(function(){ 
    return location.href.match($(this).attr("href"))
})
.addClass("active-sidebar-link");
```

Returns only filtered elements, which in this case would be the link with the current URL and adds the class `active-sidebar-link` to it.