# Active Link Based on the URL

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me.. I want to add a active class on my menu based on my URL

Here is the code

```
<div class="taglist">
<a class="automotive" title="Automotive Tag" href="#">Automotive</a>
<a class="banca" title="Banca Tag" href="#">Banca</a>
<a class="banking-pt" title="Banking Tag" href="#">Banking</a>
<a class="big-data" title="Big Data Tag" href="#">Big Data</a>
<a class="bigdata" title="BigData Tag" href="#">BigData</a>
<a class="cloud" title="Cloud Tag" href="#">Cloud</a>
</div>
```

Possible URL´s

```
http://www.whatever.com/?tag=automotive,big-data,cloud
http://www.whatever.com/?tag=automotive,big-data
http://www.whatever.com/tag/automotive
```

So, what i need is when the URL is  http://www.whatever.com/?tag=automotive,big-data i would like to add one more class, like active.

Example:

```
URL: http://www.whatever.com/?tag=automotive,big-data
```

HTML:

```
<div class="taglist">
<a class="automotive active" title="Automotive Tag" href="#">Automotive</a>
<a class="banca" title="Banca Tag" href="#">Banca</a>
<a class="banking-pt" title="Banking Tag" href="#">Banking</a>
<a class="big-data active" title="Big Data Tag" href="#">Big Data</a>
<a class="bigdata" title="BigData Tag" href="#">BigData</a>
<a class="cloud" title="Cloud Tag" href="#">Cloud</a>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery active class to menu item based on current url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593591/jquery-active-class-to-menu-item-based-on-current-url)

Comment: Yes...is true, but only works for a url with one tag (http://www.whatever.com/?tag=automotive)...if you have multiple tags (http://www.whatever.com/?tag=automotive,big-data) it doesn´t work

Comment: @LuisP.A. did you see my code? It works perfectly for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style of code work for you

```
// var url=document.URL;
var url="http://www.whatever.com/tag/automotive/";

// remove latest /
if (url[url.length-1] == "/")
{url = url.substring(0, url.length-1);}
alert(url);

// when "tag/"
if(url.indexOf("tag/") != -1){
    url = url.split('tag/')[1];
}
// when "tag="
else
{
    url = url.split('tag=')[1];
}
// split in table
var tagArray = url.split(',');
// foreach table item put active on menu links
for (var i = 0; i < tagArray.length; i++) {
        $( "."+tagArray[i] ).addClass( "active" );    
}
```

you can see the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mh7ory9n/8/

Comment: I gave you an error the single url is diferent (http://www.whatever.com/tag/automotive)

Comment: I made an example with 2 possible urls (one is comment) http://jsfiddle.net/mh7ory9n/3/

Comment: @LuisP.A. if my response satisfy you, please consider to validate my response / vote

Comment: I´m checking out..i´m with some issues...stay tuned!

Comment: Hello again...a minor problem (I think) the single url ends with a slash(/), and there before your test is without a slash in the end of the url...is it possible to fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/mh7ory9n/7/

Answer (score 0):

I just did similar example to @clement using vanilla js. You could update the array of tags using tags.push("item3") for example.

```
//var url = "http://www.whatever.com/tag/automotive/big-data/";
var url = "http://www.whatever.com?tag=automotive,big-data";
getActiveItems(url);

function getActiveItems(url) {

    if (url.indexOf("tag=") == -1) {
        if (url[url.length-1] == "/")
            url = url.substring(0, url.length-1);
        var tags = (url.split("tag/"))[1].split("/");
    } else {
        var tags = (url.split("tag="))[1].split(",");
    }

    var listElements = document.getElementById("navbar").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
        tags.map(function (elem) {
            if ((listElements[i].className).indexOf(elem) != -1) 
                listElements[i].className += ' active'
        });
    }
}
```

You can see the example running on that link: http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/xes9tvpa/

Comment: Its the same..doesn´t work with my single url (http://www.whatever.com/tag/automotive)...only works with multiple tags

Comment: @LuisP.A. I updated the example putting an if statement to control that. I am not sure if it's what you are looking for.